# CanCan - keyholder access for a user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using CanCan & Devise for user authentication & permissions.

A user can nominate a keyholder for their account, who will have different permissions. The keyholder has an attribute called 'access_id' that is the same as the id of the account they can access. What I'm trying to acheive is the following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.keyholder?
      can :read, Folder do |folder|
        folder.try(:user) == user.access_id
      end 
    else
      can :create, :all
      can :manage, :all do |all|
        all.try(:user) == user
      end
    end



  end
end
```

But with this code, the keyholder cannot access the account they are nominated to access. How do I rectify the code to make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: `folder.try(:user)` is probably returning a user object while `user.access_id` is integer. maybe you should fix that?

Comment: I tried changing the line to: folder.try(:user.id) == user.access_id but this is still saying that access is denied - how do I phrase it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
folder.user_id == user.access_id
```

assuming keyholder is logged in.

so that

```
user.keyholder? => true
user => keyholder
user.access_id => id of user who did nominate current_user
folder.user_id => id of folder owner
```

---

**edit**

if you also want that keyholder also accesses his / her folder:

```
( folder.user_id == user.access_id ) || ( folder.user_id == user.id )
```

but this one is better, put this out of your if / else statements, so that anyone, (keyholder, or regular user) can acess his / her own folder.

```
def initialize(user)
user ||= User.new # guest user

# every one reads his own folder.. or you can copy this to wherever you want
can :read, Folder do |folder|
  folder.user_id == user.id
end 

if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.keyholder?
  can :read, Folder do |folder|
    # but keyholder accesses even more
    folder.user_id == user.access_id
  end 
else
  can :create, :all
  can :manage, :all do |all|
    all.try(:user) == user
  end
end
end
```

also, alternatively, you can define can :read for keyholder multiple times. like:

```
elsif user.keyholder?
  can :read, Folder do |folder|
    folder.user_id == user.access_id
  end 
  can :read, Folder do |folder|
    folder.user_id == user.id
  end 
else
```

Comment: That's what I'm after but unfortunately they don't work. It is the keyholder who has the access_id as an attribute. I want them to only be able to access the account if that access_id matches the id of the user they are trying to access. But I can't seem to get the correct syntax! Thanks for your help!

Comment: keyholder is also a User object right? or is it another devise class?

Comment: Yes, it is a User with a keyholder boolean field set to true.

Comment: Did you implement has_one - belongs_to relationship between these two in your user.rb? if so, can you show us the code?

Comment: Yes - the user :has_one folder, and the folder :belongs_to user.

Comment: Thanks for that - I apologise, I'm still pretty new to rails, so I don't understand why I need to delve into relationships when I just want CanCan to check whether one user's access_id matches id of the user they are trying to access? I've added your suggested code and haven't got any further, but that's probably due to me being a noob!

Comment: That works, thanks so much! But it has thrown up another issue - with what happens if a keyholder wants to access their own folder. I've tried the following code, which doesn't work, but might give the gist of what I am trying to acheive: folder.user_id == (user.access_id || user.id) - any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I used something similar to where you put the read access outside of the if statements. I had it contained within the else block and that's probably why that bit wasn't working. Thanks again.